# передача данных из запроса HTTP в select angular 5

Tags: httpclient, angular5, combobox, html-select, angular

Пытаюсь получить данные из запроса с сервера ASP.Net и вывести их в выпадающий список на Angular 5/6.

Для этого создал класс:

```
export class Configuration
{
    public IdConfiguration: Number ;
    public ConfigurationLabel: String;
    public HotKey: String;
}
```

Класс сервиса, в котором выполняется запрос  `public getConfigurations()` выглядит следующим образом:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { Configuration } from '../classes/configuration';
import { catchError, map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
};

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SortingService {
  public serverUrl = 'http://localhost:9000/api';
  msgBackend: Promise<string>;


  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
   }

  public getConfigurations(): Observable<Configuration[]>{
    return this.http.get<Configuration[]>(this.serverUrl+"/configurations/get")
    .pipe(
      /*tap(batches => console.log(`fetched batch`)),*/
      catchError(this.handleError('getConfigurations', []))
    );
  }


  private handleData(data: any) {
    //console.log(data);
    this.msgBackend= data;
  } 


  private handleError<T> (operation = 'operation', result?: T) {
    return (error: any): Observable<T> => {

      // TODO: send the error to remote logging infrastructure
      console.error(error); // log to console instead

      // TODO: better job of transforming error for user consumption
      console.log(`${operation} failed: ${error.message}`);

      // Let the app keep running by returning an empty result.
      return of(result as T);
    };
  }

}
```

Ну и собственно функция subscribe

```
 getConfigurations():void{
    /*this.configurations = [
      {IdConfiguration:1, ConfigurationLabel:"Яловка", HotKey:"a"},
      {IdConfiguration:2, ConfigurationLabel:"Бык", HotKey:"b"},
    ];*/
    this._sortingService.getConfigurations()   
    .subscribe(      
      configurations =>  this.configurations = configurations
    );

  }
```

Как видно я пробовал просто создать массив конфигурация и на странице все прекрасно работает в список выводится 2 значения "Яловка" и "Бык".

HTML:

```
<span>Конфигурация: </span>
    <select>
    <option *ngFor="let configuration of configurations" [ngValue]="configuration.ConfigurationId">{{configuration.ConfigurationLabel}}</option>
  </select>
```

С данными из запроса такого результата получить не удалось - поля пустые. Либо если вместо `{{configuration.ConfigurationLabel}}` написать `{{configuration}}` выдаст следующую картину:
[image: Object object]

Сам запрос приходит в таком виде: 
[image: Данные]

Буду благодарен!

Comment: для начала посмотрите, что приходит в **configuration.ConfigurationLabel** {{configuration.ConfigurationLabel | json}}

Comment: а еще лучше в самом `configuration` - {{configuration | json}}

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо привести к configurations типу Configurations[]

```
showConfigurations():void{
    this._sortingService.getConfigurations()   
    .subscribe((configurations: Configuration[]) => this.configurations = configurations);
  }
```

В самом же запросе необходимо передавать именно данные класса

```
export class Configuration
{
    public idConfiguration: number ;
    public configurationLabel: string;
}
```